# If Statement Syntax error 1064

Tags: mysql, if-statement, syntax

I want to test a field value and alter a append a field to another table if the result of the test is true.

I dont want to create a procedure etc its a one off script I just want to pass it and its done with. But I get a 1064 error on the 'IF' int the statement bellow.

```
DELIMITER $$
IF 2 > (Select `Version` FROM `timecard`.`versionControl` WHERE `Table` = 'Employee') then
    ALTER TABLE `timecard`.`Employee`                     
      ADD COLUMN IPAddr VARCHAR(16) NULL AFTER PWord;   

    Update `timecard`.`VersionControl`   
      Set .`Version` = 2
      where `Table` = 'Employee';
  END IF $$     

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Using IF in that fashion can only be done in a stored procedure.

Comment: Ok. So how can I do the same thing another way.Or how do I pass the coloum type ie varchar, intiger etc into the procedure. If I have to write a procedure I might as well do it so it can be used as flexibly as possable

Comment: You could pass the column type as a string, build up the query as a string & create a prepared statement : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html